# R markdown cannot open URL when using download.file

Tags: r, download, r-markdown

*Note this problem only occurs on Windows.

I have the following code that runs properly out of a normal script or the console:

```
tdir <- tempdir()

stateurl <- "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip"
if(file.exists(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp",sep=""))==F){
download.file(stateurl, destfile = file.path(tdir, "States.zip"))
unzip(file.path(tdir,"States.zip"),exdir=tdir)}
```

But when placing that same script in a chunk and trying to knit to HTML in Rmarkdown, I am left with the warning "could not open URL connection."

I am lost as to the potential issue why something simple like downloading a file would run in the console but not in RMarkdown.

Comment: Initially I could not reproduce this problem (on Windows), but I gave it a few more tries and now I (partially) can.  Starting in a clean session, and repeatedly executing "Knit to HTML", sometimes leads to the indicated error, while sometimes it runs without problem.  And whether or not this works seems to be random as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the error about 50% of the time with the provided code without obvious pattern (i.e. repeateadly running "Knit to HTML" from the same session will randomly fail/work).

For me, the problem goes away if I explicitly specify `method = "libcurl"` as argument to `download.file` (instead of the default `method = "auto"`, which uses "wininet" on Windows)

```
tdir <- tempdir()

stateurl <- "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip"
if(file.exists(paste(tdir,"/cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp",sep=""))==F){
download.file(stateurl, destfile = file.path(tdir, "States.zip"), method = "libcurl")
unzip(file.path(tdir,"States.zip"),exdir=tdir)}
```

With this "Knit to HTML" is working consistently (at least for my 10+ tests).

Comment: Thanks! It seems very strange to me. After repeated tests without "method = 'libcurl'", it looks like it knits without error 50% of the time, but adding the libcurl argument fixes it. Any reason you think this might be occurring? Do you think it is a real bug with R?

Comment: I actually don't understand the reason why the behaviour appears inconsistent. If you look at the Details section of `?download.file`, it says that on Windows `"wininet"` is the default method, with optional support for `libcurl` and some additional information. But not sure if any of this explains why the results vary between repeated executions...

Comment: I don't get it.  I have a process to download from data.cityofchicago.org. It's worked for a year on 3 servers, and it started failing on June 8 on Redhat, Windows 10, and Windows 11. Clearly it's not the R version or OS version.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I was able to use `download.file` to download a jpeg from a url reference in the console, but when I used the same download.file call in rmarkdown or quarto, I got an error:

> Error in download.file(mod_image, destfile = "UA-MOD-casualty-image.jpg",  :
> cannot open URL 'http://www.mil.gov.ua/assets/images/resources/69864/47cf8333f4e8e8e367187ddd3a11c2761a1bd0cf.jpeg'
> Calls: .main ... eval_with_user_handlers -> eval -> eval -> download.file
> Execution halted

(Note, this was with MacOS 13.3.)

Rather than use download.file, I used curl::curl_download and that worked in rmarkdown and quarto.

In summary,
`download.file(url_for_image, destfile = "UA-MOD-casualty-image.jpg", method = "libcurl")`
and
`curl::curl_download(url_for_image, destfile = "UA-MOD-casualty-image.jpg", quiet = TRUE)`
both work in the console, but only curl_download works in rmarkdown or quarto.

I don't know why download.file fails in quarto and rmarkdown. Presumably there's some interaction with knitr. Note that I explicitly tried to set method to 'libcurl'.

Comment: I had the same problem with macOS 14.2.1, R version 4.3.2 and Quarto 1.4.549. Your alternative with curl::curl_download() saved my day!